# Implementing a device driver as a set of kernel modules

Tags: linux, architecture, kernel, kernel-module

I have a user-space library that is used to communicate to a device over a serial port. The library is fairly complex and performs many tasks including putting headers onto payloads, fragmenting the messages, sending messages, processing responses, initializing the device, etc...

I'd like to move this library to kernel-space and am considering breaking up the library into several well-defined kernel modules so that

- I can leave the door open to swap out layers in the future (for example swapping out the USART layer with an SPI layer).
- Development will be easier. If it were divided up, I could migrate the library to kernel-space piece-by-piece.

Has anyone ever done something like this before? What are the best ways (in terms of efficiency) to communicate between kernel modules? Are there any pitfalls I should avoid?

Finally, are there any good examples of drivers that are implemented as a set of kernel modules?

Comment: The general advice is to avoid moving things from user-space to kernel-space. If your user-space solution works, why do you want to move it to kernel-space??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All kernel modules run in the same address space. To call one module from another, you need to export some symbols: functions or global variables. Though probably the use of global variables in this case is a bad style. Note that your exported symbols will be in the same name space as all other kernel symbols. To avoid name conflicts you should use some well-defined prefix for them, usually the name of the module and an underscore. So if one of your modules is called `foo` and you want to export function `bar()`, you could use code like this in `foo` module:

```
void foo_bar(const char *prm) {
  printk (KERN_INFO "foo_bar(%s) was called\n", prm);
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(foo_bar);
```

In the other module, say buz, just call this function:

```
foo_bar("qux");
```

**Be noted**, that in the kernel module you can't use libc (or other libraries) features and many usual things like memory management, file I/O, networking and so on, could be really complicated. Also note that kernel module debugging is not a trivial task and many errors will cause kernel panic instead of harmless Segmentation Fault.

So think thrice before moving some working library to the kernel space. Possibly it might be better to break your library into the same "modules" but keep it (or most part of it) in userspace.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but ALSA consists of many distinct modules for each different sound chip, and several common ones that the others depend on:

```
$ lsmod | grep snd
snd_hrtimer            12744  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek   330769  1 
snd_hda_intel          33390  2 
snd_usb_audio         118064  0 
snd_hda_codec         104802  2 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_pcm                96714  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
snd_hwdep              13668  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
snd_usbmidi_lib        25371  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_rawmidi            30547  2 snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61896  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              29991  3 snd_hrtimer,snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14540  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
snd                    68266  16 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec,snd_pcm,snd_hwdep,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
soundcore              12680  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18529  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
```

Reconstructing the dependency graph is left as an exercise to the reader.